# Is it possible to use AspNetIdentity with Duende IdentityServer Backend for Frontend (BFF) approach?

Tags: asp.net-identity, duende-identity-server

So lately I am trying to setup my Blazor Webassembly (Core hosted) application with Duende IdentityServer. Although most information is well documented, I can't seem to find any examples on how to integrate `AspNetIdentity` with Blazor WASM.

The tutorial of using Identityserver with Blazor WASM follows the use of the 'Backend for Frontend (BFF)' approach, so I did that as well. But when I look at the 'Using ASP.NET Core Identity' tutorial, all examples use the

```
.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        // ...
    })
```

approach instead of the

```
.AddBff(options => {
       
    })
```

approach.

So the question is, is it even possible to use `AspNetIdentity` with BFF, if so, where do I add the configuration in my startup? Any pointers to a tutorial or example of this approach would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @MDZand thank you for the link, it pointed me in the right direction. In the end it seemed that the default Blazor WebAssembly template, with 'Use Individual Accounts', was all I needed. Though the docs of Duende suggest I could use the BFF approach, though I think it lacks the information on how to customize it (e.g. use your own login page, using AspNetIdentity, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use BFF along with AspnetIdentity and IdentityServer, you need to setup a separate project for the BFF server(there's a template). In the BFF project, you specify the OIDC authority as your IdentityServer and you need to setup the BFF project as a client.
I don't know Blazor but using the Angular cli, you also need to setup a proxy so that the cookie can be shared between the client and server app.

The following article and sample were really informative to me :
:
https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/lets-make-our-spa-more-secure-by-consuming-a-duende-bff-with-angular

https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/IdentityServer/v6/BFF/AngularBffSample